# Cross compile application built with MS Visual studio 2010

Tags: windows, linux, visual-c++, cross-compiling

I have written a code, basically for windows using VC++ with development environment MS Visual Studio 2010.

Note: **it is console- application and does not contain GUI**. So I would like to cross- compile.

I want my code to compile to Linux as well without modifying the code. I mean, I Wish to do cross-compile. Can anyone please describe me briefly on "how-to" or re-direct me to few posts on StackOverflow.

Comment: Cross-compiling is the process of compiling for a different target platform than your toolchain is running on. It's not about making code portable, i.e. compilable on another platform. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: @Jim Yes, my ultimate plan is to make code Portable. Here i would like to build Linux executable (.bin file). But my source code comes from Windows and I am also using Win32 API (console-application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can I'm sure dig up a linux-targeted version of GCC cross compiled to run under windows (or build it from sources using a version of GCC which targets the windows platform, such and MINGW's or cygwin's) it may prove easier to install a smaller linux distribution, perhaps a console-only one, in a virtual machine.

As you mentioned, you have done I/O using the WIN32 API.  You will need to change this to unix/posix type methods, probably including learning about changing the terminal settings, which can be a bit of a learning experience.   To know that you got this right, you'll need to be able to test it.  Building the "linux" version of your code under cygwin and running it on your windows box might work, but it's probably best to gain some familiarity with the actual target operating system.

Just verifying that your windows executable runs under Wine which Dani mentioned wouldn't be a bad idea either.  There's also a library, Winelib, that aims to help with porting by providing substitutes for the windows calls when trying to compile your code for linux.

Finally, just switching compilers from MSVC to GCC, regardless if you target linux or windows or cygwin, is probably going to require some changes to your source code.  MSVC will tolerate a number of dodgy things that GCC won't, for example in how you declare structs.  The reverse is probably also true.  But with some learning and regularly feeding your project to both compilers, you can maintain portable code.

Comment: I guess you have almost got me the answer. But the code is already running on Windows and modifying it for Posix/unix will take time. Will try this way as well. But are there any libraries to compile the source code in linux?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your using ANSI version of c++ (no clr staff ect.) and it should compile on linux as well.

you might want to look for a tool that converts csproj into makefiles, or write them yourself.

Comment: I do use Win32 API to handle few keyboard and mouse related messages. I just need to get my code compile and build on Linux. What tool would you suggest? :-)

Comment: Win32 API is WINDOWS. you can't use it on linux without changing. look at mono project - it should enable using dot net on linux, but, I don't know about mouse related messaging. use use mouse on a console app ? There is also a product called WINE. check it out as well.

Comment: I got you! Here in my application, I use mouse events. I do not need/have any GUI module. What would you suggest, is there any API common for Linux and Windows to handle hardware (Mouse) events? Mono is a good tool. But as you said, It does not suppose to support Mouse handlers.

Comment: You Can't, as native linux has no mouse, and when you use a graphic environment - each one has it's own library - as win32. there is X/Monit and many more. You will need to target your code against the right library I guess. you can insert #IFDEFs in your code to make it work on both systems, but you will have to write something to make it work.